# Python -- Determine Frequency of numbers showing up in dice rolls

Tags: python, frequency, dice

these are the functions used to roll the dice.

```
def roll() -> int:
    ''' Return a roll of two dice, 2-12
    '''
    die1 = randint(1, 6)
    die2 = randint(1, 6)
    return die1 + die2

def roll_dice(n:int):
    '''list the results of rolls'''
    for i in range(n):
        print(roll())
```

Now i need help to make function to create a list of stats of the numbers rolled.

for example: after printing the said function it should print out somethings like this according to my lab:

```
Distribution of dice rolls

 2:    55 ( 2.8%)  **
 3:   129 ( 6.5%)  ******
 4:   162 ( 8.1%)  ********
 5:   215 (10.8%)  **********
 6:   279 (14.0%)  *************
 7:   341 (17.1%)  *****************
 8:   271 (13.6%)  *************
 9:   210 (10.5%)  **********
10:   168 ( 8.4%)  ********
11:   112 ( 5.6%)  *****
12:    58 ( 2.9%)  **
-----------------
     2000 rolls
```

help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? If so include the code. If you're trying to make us do your homeowork, try something first and ask for specifics.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: @mgilson those are function annotations: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

Comment: @Bakuriu -- Thanks.  Now that you mention it, I might have seen those once before ...

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def roll_dice(n):
    '''list the results of rolls'''
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for i in range(n):
        res = roll()
        d[res] += 1    #accumulate results
        print(res)

    print ("RESULTS")
    #sort and print results.  Since there's only 11 items, 
    # There is no sense using `iteritems()` here.  We'd 
    # just have to change it for py3k...
    for key,value in sorted(d.items()):  
        percent = float(value)/n*100
        #print results.  Use explicit field widths to make sure the "bargraph" is aligned.
        print ('{0:2d}:{1:4d}\t({2:6f}%)\t{3}'.format(key,value,percent,int(percent)*'*'))


roll_dice(2000)
```

Comment: Instead of `defaultdict` you could also use `Counter` like `d = Counter(roll() for _ in range(n))`. [python >= 2.7 or >= 3.1]

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with a graphical output, you can use the [histogram method from matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/histogram_demo.html).

Or you can manually create the bins you need, here the integers 2 to 12, and simply count how many rolls goes in each bin. Normalize by your number of roll to get the percentage and add a star for each 1% (apparently rounded down).

This yields the following code (python 2.X) after a few modifications:

```
import random
import math

def roll():
    ''' Return a roll of two dice, 2-12
    '''
    die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    return die1 + die2

def roll_dice(npts):
    '''list the results of rolls'''
    bins = dict([(n,0) for n in xrange(2,13,1)])
    for n in xrange(npts):
        idx = roll()
        print idx
        bins[idx] = bins[idx] + 1

    for n in xrange(2,13,1):
        pct = bins[n]/float(npts) * 100.0
        pct_star = ''
        for i in xrange(int(math.floor(pct))):
           pct_star = pct_star + '*'
        str = "{0:.1f}%".format(pct).rjust(5,' ')
        print "{0:2d}:  {1:5d} ({2:s})  {3:s}".format(n,bins[n],str,pct_star)
    print "------------------"
    print "{0:10d} rolls".format(npts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    npts = 20000
    roll_dice(2000)
```

which outputs

```
 2:    569 ( 2.8%)  **
 3:   1131 ( 5.7%)  *****
 4:   1770 ( 8.8%)  ********
 5:   2229 (11.1%)  ***********
 6:   2778 (13.9%)  *************
 7:   3307 (16.5%)  ****************
 8:   2703 (13.5%)  *************
 9:   2231 (11.2%)  ***********
10:   1633 ( 8.2%)  ********
11:   1128 ( 5.6%)  *****
12:    598 ( 3.0%)  **
------------------
     20000 rolls
```

Comment: nice, i've tested this code. the bins should be with initialized 0 though. I would use 2-12 as keys, instead of n-2.

Comment: But then I would have to use a dictionary and not a list right? How can I get a list whose first index is not 0?

Comment: yes, use a dict(). every list is either empty or has an index 0.

Comment: And I guess on such easy problem there is no performance penalty in using dict... I'm coming from Fortran so I don't always think of the more complex but useful structures.